# PHP/Imagick Composite Gif & PDF outputs nothing?

Tags: php, imagick

I have the following code to overlay a gif into a pdf and return it to the browser for download.

```
<?php

$first = new Imagick('PDF/page.pdf'); 
$second = new Imagick('images/image.gif'); 

$first->setImageColorspace($second->getImageColorspace() ); 

$first->compositeImage($second, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 1630, 2100); 

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.pdf"');
echo $first;

?>
```

I don't get any errors or anything, just a blank page & no downloads... can anybody tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: Check the server's error log. Blank screens in a browser usually indicate `display_errors` is off and something blew up. If things had gotten as far as your `header()` calls, you'd have gotten at least a download prompt and get a 0-byte file.

Comment: JKirchartz: is this problem of yours is related with your other question about creating barcodes? If it is so, consider my answer in the other page. It will solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there's nothing wrong with this code, I had my server misconfigured... and then my numbers for the offset were way off (because they're not the same on the server as they were in photoshop)

Answer (score 0):

Remove headers and try again. May be you have some additional error text written in your pdf data. And be sure display errors are on.

Comment: it turns out I had some config error with php & imagick... now it outputs the PDF but doesn't overlay the gif...